# Termination issue in pcre

Tags: regex, xml, pcre, rules, snort

actually I am building rules for my Snort IDS and trying to solve a problem with the Billion Laughs attack. It is nothing else than just recursive call of predefined variables. Snort rules may contain pcre and so i try to build an intelligent rule for this attack. This may be a simple form of this attack, with random lines inbetween the ENTITY-lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE data [
<!ENTITY a0 "dos" >
<!ENTITY a1 "&a0;&a0;&a0;&a0;">
<!ENTITY a2 "&a1;&a1;&a1;&a1;&a1;&a1;">
<!ENTITY a1 "&a2;&a2;&a2;&a2;&a2;&a2;">
test
<!ENTITY a1 "&a2;&a2;&a2;&ertertert;&a2;&a2;">
<!ENTITY a1 "&a2;&a2;&a2;&ertertert;&a2;&a2;">


<!ENTITY a1 "&a2;&a2;&a2;&a2;&a2;&a2;">
d
dd

<html abc>
a

<!ENTITY a2 "&a3;&a3;&a3;&a3;&a3;">
<!ENTITY a1 "&a0;&a0;&a0;&a0;&d5;">
]>
<data>&a2;</data>
```

And this is my actual rule:

```
(<!ENTITY\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s"(&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;){4,}">(\s?)[^]]*){5,}
```

To explain the goal that i want to achieve:

The rule has to trigger, whenever there are at least 5 ENTITY-lines with at least 4 of &-parameters. If all 5 lines are followed one after another, there is no problem,
but the ENTITY-lines do not need to come one after another. So that i have to catch everything else in between two ENTITY-lines which makes the whole thing to a big termination problem, because [^]]* catches everything except a ] and also catches whole ENTITY-lines and makes my quantifier {5,} totaly useless. Actually i can't find any good solution for my problem.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: This works perfect at the first sight. Now I have to understand it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)<!ENTITY\s[a-z0-9]*\s"(&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;){4,}">(?:.*?<!ENTITY\s[a-z0-9]*\s"(&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;){4,}">){4,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS8n5U/1)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - DOTALL mode on, `.` now matches any chars
- `<!ENTITY` - a literal `<!ENTITY` substring
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[a-z0-9]*` - 0+ letters / digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `"` - a `"`
- `(&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;){4,}` - 4 or more repetitions of `&`, 1+ alphanumeric chars and then `;`
- `">` - a `">` substring
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching....

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `<!ENTITY\s[a-z0-9]*\s"(&[a-zA-Z0-9]+;){4,}">` - same pattern as above
- `){4,}` - ... 4 or more times.

Comment: I just don't get the function of the non-capturing group. Does it change anything to leave the (?: out?

Comment: @Mischu Only use capturing groups if you need to use the captured value. Use non-capturing ones when you just need to group a sequence of patterns (to quantifier them, or when you need an alternation).

Comment: Why do you need the non-capturing group at all?

Comment: @Bacon To quantify the sequence of subpatterns with `{4,}`.

Comment: Ho, I see. The first {4,0} is for the number of references in the entity, the last one is for the number of entities. Thanks!